suma de matrices
como podria sumar los valores de 2 matrices en una tercera, al hacerlo de esta manera c es un array simple no una matriz
def suma_matrices(a, b):
    if not matrices_compatibles(a, b):
        return("Error las matrices deben tener el mismo area")
    else:
        c = []
        for i in range(0, len(a)):
            for j in range(0, len(a[i])):
                c.append(a[i][j] + b[i][j])
    return c


Si no es un ejercicio, puedes usar numpy para operar con matrices

Andas bastante cerca
La función de suma:
def suma(a, b):
    c = []                     # Matriz de salida
    for fila in range(len(a)):
        fila_out = []          # Una fila vacia
        for col in range(len(a[0])):
            sum = a[fila][col] + b[fila][col]
            fila_out.append(sum)
        c.append(fila_out)     # Agregar la fila a la salida
    return c

La diferencia es que primero se arma un fila con la suma, y luego ese fila (una lista formalmente), se agrega a la matriz de salida c. O sea, armas una lista de filas.
Fijate que no controlo los errores; si las matrices no son de igual dimensión se producira un IndexError, que debes atrapar con un try-except. Asi se maneja mejor el error.
Test
a = [[1, 2], [3, 4]]
b = [[4, 5], [8, 9]]
c = suma(a, b)
print(c)

produce
[[5, 7], [11, 13]]

Process finished with exit code 0

Test 2
try:
    a = [[1, 2], [3, 4]]
    b=[[1],[2]]
    c = suma(a, b)
    print(c)
except IndexError:
    print("Matrices de distinta dimensión")

que produce
Matrices de distinta dimensión

Process finished with exit code 0


Estás muy cerca, puedes llevarlo a buen puerto, creando una matriz vacia:
def suma_matrices( a, b ):
    
    if not matrices_compatibles(a, b):
        return("Error las matrices deben tener el mismo area")

      # creo una matriz vacia, con el mismo tamaño de "a"
    out = [[ 0 for _ in range( len( a ))] for _ in range( len( a[0]))]

    for i in range(0, len(a)):
        for j in range( 0, len( a[ i ] )):
              # instancio cada item de la matriz, con la suma correspondiente
            out[ i ][ j ] = a[ i ][ j ] + b[ i ][ j ]
    return out


En Python las listas son siempre objetos "unidimensionales" que contienen referencias a cualquier objeto Python válido. Para simular una array de dos dimensiones (o más) lo que se hace es usar listas de listas en la que cada sublista representa una fila. En tu caso agregas las sumas directamente a la lista "raiz" en vez de crear cada sublista (fila), agregar las sumas a la fila y luego agregarla fila a la lista matriz.
En vez de indizado + range() como demuestran las otras respuestas, otra posibilidad es usar zip()
def suma_matrices(a, b):
    mat_sum = []
    for fila_a, fila_b in zip(a, b):
        fila_sum = []
        for num_a, num_b in zip(fila_a, fila_b):
            fila_sum.append(num_a + num_b)
        mat_sum.append(fila_sum)
    return mat_sum

Lo mismo se puede hacer usando listas por compresión:
def suma_matrices(a, b):
    return [[num_a + num_b for num_a, num_b in zip(fila_a, fila_b)] for fila_a, fila_b in zip(a, b)]

O generalizando para que acepte cualquier numero de matrices como argumentos:
def suma_matrices(*matrices):
    return [[sum(nums) for nums in zip(*filas)] for filas in zip(*matrices)]


>>> a = [[10, 11], [12, 13]]
>>> b = [[14, 15], [16, 17]]
>>> c = [[18, 19], [20, 21]]
>>> suma_matrices(a, b, c)
[[42, 45], [48, 51]]



zip() itera en paralelo sobre multiples iterables. Si le pasamos dos listas, primero retorna una tupla con el primer elemento de ambas, luego otra con el segundo, etc. Va emparejando items de ambos iterables. Esto se generaliza para cualquier numero de iterables:
  >>> for nums in zip([1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]):
  ...     print(nums)
  ...     
  (1, 3, 5)
  (2, 4, 6)

  # O dado que puedes desestructurar/desempaquetar el iterable en el for
  >>> for a, b, c in zip([1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]):
  ...     print(a, b, c)
  ...     
  1 3 5
  2 4 6


Si se busca eficiencia, las bibliotecas de terceros especializadas en cálculo numérico y simbólico como NumPy o SymPy ofrecen métodos optimizados para la suma de matrices:

>>> import numpy as np

>>> a = np.array([
        [10, 11],
        [12, 13]])

>>> b = np.array([
        [14, 15],
        [16, 17]])

>>> c = np.array([
        [18, 19],
        [20, 21]])

>>> a + b + c
array([[42, 45],
       [48, 51]])




>>> import sympy

>>> x = sympy.Symbol("x")

>>> a = sympy.Matrix([
...     [2*x,   11],
...     [ 12,  4*x]])

>>> b = sympy.Matrix([
...     [ 8*x,   15],
...     [16*x, 17*x]])

>>> a + b
Matrix([
[     10*x,   26],
[16*x + 12, 21*x]])


